# How to allow the application to communicate back to the on premise equipment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vpc

One of the questions in a AWS practice exam is as below:

*You are a solutions architect who has moved to a manufacturing company who has very legacy applications. One of these applications needs to communicate with services which are currently hosted on premise. The people who wrote this application have left the company and there is nothing to document how the application works. You need to ensure that this application can be hosted in a bespoke VPC but still be able to communicate to the back end services which are hosted on premise. Which of the three answers below will allow the application to communicate back to the on premise equipment without the need to reprogram the application?*

And one of the correct answer was indicated to be:

***You should ensure the VPC has an internet gateway attached to it so that you can establish a site to site VPN with the on premise environment.***

From the VPC faq, my understanding is you do not need internet gateway for VPN to work.

From [VPC FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/)

> Q. How does a hardware VPN connection work with Amazon VPC?
>
> A hardware VPN connection connects your VPC to your datacenter. Amazon supports Internet Protocol security (IPsec) VPN connections. Data transferred between your VPC and datacenter routes over an encrypted VPN connection to help maintain the confidentiality and integrity of data in transit. **An Internet gateway is not required to establish a hardware VPN connection**.

Anyone have experience with VPN on AWS, please clarify.

*THIS QUESTION DOES NOT LACKS RESEARCH*

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: For the genius who gave -1(apparently for 'lack of research') for the question, I understand that you are too headstrong. Digging through the FAQ's and asking for clarification from someone with practical experience is not lack of research. Have some decency.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that discussions about this question can also be found at:

- A Cloud Guru: [Internet Gateway vs Virtual Private Gateway](https://acloud.guru/course/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discuss/-KWnNOXPpcTFD0X-FYzW/internet-gateway-vs-virtual-private-gateway)
- A Cloud Guru: [VPC - Internet Gateway for a Site to Site VPN? - Correct Answer?](https://acloud.guru/course/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discuss/-KaGODBDh5xrqR_wry2p/vpc-internet-gateway-for-a-site-to-site-vpn-correct-answer)
- A Cloud Guru: [Direct Connect question](https://acloud.guru/course/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discuss/-KYg4yc1Un3wpnGKV3mH/direct-connect-question)

The question apparently asks for 3 correct answers out of 5. The question is badly written and **does not have a correct set of answers**.

The connection would need to be either via **AWS Direct Connect** or a **VPN Connection**, both of which connect to an Amazon VPC via a **Virtual Private Gateway** rather than an Internet Gateway.

It would be possible to establish a Software VPN connection back to on-premise, which would require software configuration, an Internet Gateway and a Public IP address (for the Software VPN). However, the provided answers make no mention of a Software VPN.